# redraw a portion of a panel

Tags: java, jpanel

I'm doing Java exercises from a book. One says to redraw just a portion of a panel when refreshing, but doesn't give sufficient clues how to do it:

(from the exercise)
When you repaint the entire viewing area of a panel, sometimes only a tiny portion of the viewing area is changed. You can improve the performance by repainting only the affected area, but do not
invoke super.paintComponent(g) when repainting the panel, because this will cause the entire viewing area to be cleared.

It should be apply-able for any problem, but for example this: it draws line segments (starting from the center) when pushing a,w,s,d keys, but not keeping the previously drawn lines

```
public class PartialRepaint extends JFrame{
    private DrawBoard dr=new DrawBoard();
    private int x,y,dx,dy;
    private boolean boo=true;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        PartialRepaint fr=new PartialRepaint();
        fr.setSize(400, 400);
        fr.setLocation(300, 200);
        fr.setTitle("KeyListening");
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setVisible(true);

    }
    public PartialRepaint(){
        add(dr);
        KListen listen=new KListen();
        dr.addKeyListener(listen);
        dr.setFocusable(true);
    }
    public class DrawBoard extends JPanel{
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){

            if(boo){
                //super.paintComponent(g);
                x=dr.getWidth()/2;
                y=dr.getHeight()/2;
            }
            int x1=x+dx;
            int y1=y+dy;
            g.drawLine(x, y, x1, y1);
            x=x1; y=y1;
           } 
    }
    public class KListen implements KeyListener{
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyChar()=='a'){
                dx=-10; dy=0;
            }
            if(e.getKeyChar()=='d'){
                dx=10; dy=0;
            }
            if(e.getKeyChar()=='w'){
                dx=0; dy=-10;
            }
            if(e.getKeyChar()=='s'){
                dx=0; dy=10;
            }
            boo=false;
            repaint();
        }
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {        }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you repaint just that component? It's an exercise so doing some critical thinking and problem solving is expected.

Comment: The exercise task as it’s written here is nonsense. Just call [`repaint(Rectangle)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint-java.awt.Rectangle-) rather than `repaint()` and the JRE will take care of the rest. Especially the “do not invoke super.paintComponent(g)” part can (and should) be ignored then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not redrawing the DrawingPanel at all.  It's just drawing the new line segments based on your key presses.

Here's your code modified to start on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (EDT) and formatted.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PartialRepaint implements Runnable {
    private DrawBoard dr = new DrawBoard();
    private int x, y, dx, dy;
    private boolean boo = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new PartialRepaint());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        KListen listen = new KListen();
        dr.addKeyListener(listen);
        dr.setFocusable(true);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("KeyListening");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(dr);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class DrawBoard extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6566116168990163107L;

        public DrawBoard() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            if (boo) {
                // super.paintComponent(g);
                x = dr.getWidth() / 2;
                y = dr.getHeight() / 2;
            }
            int x1 = x + dx;
            int y1 = y + dy;
            g.drawLine(x, y, x1, y1);
            x = x1;
            y = y1;
        }
    }

    public class KListen implements KeyListener {
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyChar() == 'a') {
                dx = -10;
                dy = 0;
            }
            if (e.getKeyChar() == 'd') {
                dx = 10;
                dy = 0;
            }
            if (e.getKeyChar() == 'w') {
                dx = 0;
                dy = -10;
            }
            if (e.getKeyChar() == 's') {
                dx = 0;
                dy = 10;
            }
            boo = false;
            dr.repaint();
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This must be one method to resolve the problem. SwingUtilities haven't been covered by the book yet. It's weird that it didn't give useful guidance as it did before. Thx for you answer.